# LPSTR (Char*) in .NET

Tags: .net

How do you declare a `char*` in .NET?

Comment: It depends.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: I was trying to declare a string on heap.

Comment: Then `String s = "foo";` is all you need.

Comment: does it allocate memory on managed or unmanaged heap?

Comment: You can't allocate on the unmanaged heap in .net! It's always on the managed heap or the stack. (without pinvoke'ing HeapAlloc or anything stupid like that)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't. That's what `System.String` is for. If you need to interop with native DLL's, [see this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx).

Comment: It depends what it's being used for.  `byte[]` may be closer.

Answer (score 3):

> What exactly are you trying to do?

I didn't see your comment. I guess we posted at the same time. String, being a reference type, will be stored in the heap (the value). While the location where the string value is should be on stack. Although I am not too sure since string does not behave as a 100% reference type.

You can create pointers in .NET through unsafe code. Although one should do that with utmost care or else can end up with weird and unexpected errors.